# как заменить html код на другой html с другого сайта?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = 'https://site.com/2.html';
```

заменяет на текст,а нужно на код.

надо реализовать без get запросов,т.к. сработает защита.

```js
//var site - содержимое другого домена: https://site.com/2.html
    var site = "replaced";
    function replace(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = site;
    };
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>a</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick="replace();">replace</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Скачать текст с сайта — это HTTP GET запрос. Поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос — никак

Comment: ясно,а обойти cors как нибудь можно? не использую параметры запуска.

Comment: Нет, для того cors и есть, чтоб не обходить его. Скачивайте его через свой сервер в php-коде, например (если у вас сервер вообще есть)